# Issue with WebElement.SendKeys(path): org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found

Tags: java, jenkins, testing, filepath

I am having an issue uploading a file using Seleinum code when running on Jenkins.  My Selenium code is working fine locally and is able to uploads and finishes the test. However, when running on Jenkins, the WebElement.SendKeys(..) is throwing exception that says :org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found  ". I initiated a new File(..) in the code and tested the file existence by file.exists() and it does exist.

```
driver.get(Configuration.getEnvArg("test_url")+"mylist/doc-upload");
String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String appendPath = File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "files" + File.separator + fileName + "." + fileExt;
File file = new File(path);
LOGGER.info(path + " is exist: " + file.exists());
LOGGER.info("absolute path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id(submitId));
el.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());  // exception is thrown at this point.
pause(20);
```

```
(I replaced part of the path with xxx for posting purpose.)

invalid argument: File not found : /tmp/jenkins/workspace/xxxx/regression-tests/src/main/resources/files/dummy.png
20:49:30    (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)
20:49:30  Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
20:49:30  System info: host: 'Unknown', ip: 'Unknown', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-1095-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
20:49:30  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
20:49:30  Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.75, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.WI0TqR}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:46837}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
20:49:30  Session ID: 8c8f0738dbd321b5fb7ccb6a46adadf817b61366f1a9b4054586695693c69e5d
20:49:30  - com.qaprosoft.zafira.log.domain.MetaInfoMessage@236ded2c
20:49:30  - com.qaprosoft.zafira.log.domain.MetaInfoMessage@874bd76
20:49:30  - error processing.  Falling back to alternate logic.
20:49:30  org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found : /tmp/jenkins/workspace/xxxx/regression-tests/src/main/resources/files/dummy.png
20:49:30    (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)
20:49:30  Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
20:49:30  System info: host: 'Unknown', ip: 'Unknown', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-1095-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
20:49:30  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
20:49:30  Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.75, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.WI0TqR}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:46837}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
20:49:30  Session ID: 8c8f0738dbd321b5fb7ccb6a46adadf817b61366f1a9b4054586695693c69e5d
20:49:30    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
20:49:30    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
20:49:30    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
20:49:30    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
20:49:30    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
20:49:30    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
20:49:30    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
20:49:30    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
20:49:30    at com.qaprosoft.carina.core.foundation.webdriver.listener.EventFiringSeleniumCommandExecutor.execute(EventFiringSeleniumCommandExecutor.java:49)
20:49:30    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
20:49:30    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
20:49:30    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:106)
20:49:30    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
20:49:30    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
20:49:30    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
20:49:30    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
20:49:30    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.lambda$new$0(EventFiringWebDriver.java:404)
20:49:30    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
20:49:30    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement.sendKeys(EventFiringWebDriver.java:429)
```

Any advise is appreciated.

Thank you,
Grace

Comment: If your code works locally, and not on Jenkins, then this is an issue with the file path itself, and doesn't have anything to do with Selenium. I recommend comparing your local file path vs. the Jenkins file path from your error message and try to spot the difference. The issue is that your file is not located in the path you are entering. You may need to write a custom method to get the dynamic file path. Is your file located in your project directory?

Comment: is "path" ever defined?  I see "userDir" and "appendPath".

Comment: It is possible that this is caused by permission issue. please check if you or the jenkins job has read/ write access.

Comment: re: Christine, yes the file is within the project directory.  I did a new File(path).exists() and the file does exist. re: @pcalkins, yeah, I didn't copy is properly.  path is defined as such String path = userDir + appendPath;.  re:Sureshmani, I will check.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.
Instead of using `sendKeys(..)`, I used `ExtendedWebElement` from core method:
public void `doAttachFile(String filePath)`.  It worked perfectly.
Per my understanding, it specifies `LocalFileDetector` into the driver automatically, which allows it to find the file in the machine in which the code is running in instead of in a remote machine.
My issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi @mystackoverflow , can you provide codes for your solution pls ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the @mystackoverflow's answer and the following page https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.openqa.selenium.remote.LocalFileDetector led me to the solution.

Must be set the driver localfiledetector:

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

More information and code example to file upload: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/remote_webdriver/#local-file-detector